# Trying to install firefox on Linux on Crouton but cannot bypass user agreement

Tags: software-installation, firefox, chromebook, crouton

a friend is trying to install Firefox on an Ubuntu loaded in Crouton in a Chromebook. Technically, all they have to do is enter the sudo command to install firefox, but apparently a user agreement window pops up after installation and doesn't allow them to continue. There is an "okay" at the end but clicking on it doesn't do anything. As they cannot screenshot, this is their description:

There's a fuchsia background. At the top in grey it says "Package configuration"
then in the middle there's a large grey box. At the very top there's a piece of scarlet text that reads "Configuring ttf-mscorefonts-installer". It doesn't move, even when you scroll down. The text inside is black and reads "TrueType core fonts for the Web EULA" at the top and then "END-USER LICENSE AGREEMENT FOR MICROSOFT SOFTWARE", then the rest is the agreement. When you scroll down to the very bottom, it reads "Reference:" then gives a link. At the bottom there's a piece of stationery text that reads, " < Ok >", but it's unclickable.

Is there a way to bypass this? We downloaded twice but came across the same problem so it doesn't seem like it's a bug in the installer itself.

Also this is our first time trying Linux so do be gentle :P

Comment: You need to hit "tab" and it will focus on the button.

Answer (score 2):

On that type of screen, you move the cursor around by pressing the Tab key.  When it reaches the field you desire, press the Space bar to make an selection.

Comment: isn't it the space key

Comment: Enter key "presses" the currently selected button or the default button.  Space "presses" the currently selected button.  So yeah, space is probably better, editing.